# How to get screenshot of equal size with selenium webdriver?

Tags: screenshot, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to take screenshot using Selenium Webdriver.

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(File_Location));
```

Now the issue is that for IE and Firefox the size of the screenshots differ even though I set dimension of window.

Can anybody give me suggestion how can I get screenshots of same size for all browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The different drivers implement screenshots in different ways, IEDriver will produce differing sizes based upon the version of IE.

There have been a series of bugs raised on this, this one probably tells you all you need to know and validates this answer:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5332&can=1&q=screenshot%20size&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Specifically

> **Project Member #3 james.h....@gmail.com** Screenshots in the current
>   WebDriver API mean full page screenshots. Unlike other browsers, the
>   only way to get IE to render the full page is to have the IE window
>   large enough to draw the entire page. In other words, to resize the
>   window. For IE, we must either live with a resize, or not take
>   full-page screenshots. This is a limitation of IE; there's nothing the
>   IE driver can do to work around it. If you want to take a screenshot
>   of only the visible viewport, without a resize, you can use the
>   Windows API PrintWindow function.  **Status: WorkingAsIntended**

Comment: I tried resizing the windows but no luck. I still get images of different size. Also how to implement PrintWindow function in java. Can you anybody provide a snippet of code that I can see.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear and didn't put the first line of my answer in 48pt bold...  **YOU CAN'T** get screenshots of a consistent size.  Also using a Java Robot class won't help unless you are running the test on the machine that is driving the browser.

Comment: I was trying to follow project member comment "For IE, we must either live with a resize". My bad!

Comment: Can there be anything done taking same size screenshot for firefox?

Comment: There is no guarantee as to the screenshot size in any driver binding.

Comment: @Ardescon any idea if this has changed?

Comment: Not yet, however when the W3C spec comes out of draft it may change to the whole DOM (http://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#screenshots).  Bear in mind that when the W3C spec first comes out the existing driver implementations will probably not be compliant

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EventFiringWebDriver efDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
File scrFile = efDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(File_Location));
```

Comment: I tried this code but still I am getting screenshots of different sizes.

Comment: Anybody else has some suggestion?